# Pool.map just hangs -- how to do exception handling

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have the following code:

```
pool = Pool(10)
pool.map(run_update_procedure, titles_to_update)
```

Sometimes the `pool.map` will only work on about 18 of the 20 `titles` above. This causes the program to hang.

Is there a way to do something like:

```
try:
    pool.map(...)
```

So that if the map fails the function continues? How would I build in this exception handling to multiprocessing?

Basically, I want to kill the thread if it doesn't finish within `x` time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My recommendation would be to either (preferably) fix `run_update_procedure` to timeout or otherwise behave better ([here's](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577853-timeout-decorator-with-multiprocessing/) a potential snippet that could help), rather than hanging, *or* switch to `multiprocessing.Pool`'s `apply_async` or `map_async`, and supply a `timeout` argument to `AsyncResult.get()`.

Example:

```
pool = Pool(10)
result = pool.map_async(run_update_procedure, titles_to_update)
try:
    updates = result.get(timeout=x)
except TimeoutError:
    # handle timeout
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please show a code example of how I'd use `map_async` in the above example?